# SSMS Export to CSV or copy paste break comment column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, export-to-csv, management-studio-express

I have simple table with 8-10 columns and one of the columns is a comment `column` with can have about 500 characters of text with line breaks also.

The problem is that when I export data using SSMS without the `Comment` column it exports to CSV or even copy paste also works fine.

But when I export the `comment` column which has multiline text with line breaks it breaks the CSV file as well as copy page doesn't work properly. It add linebreak based text in new row of excel.

How can I get around this so that rich text column is exported in one column of the row in a tabular format?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `comment` column ?

Comment: anyway i resolved itss by exporting database Task --> Export data to excel.. this way it exported column data without breaking excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

in recent version of SSMS, there's an option to retain or not the carriage return/line feed.

[image]